# Как отправлять определенную куку в каждом ответе от сервера?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, yii2

Новые версии Google Chrome сейчас начали активно требовать куку SameSite и если ее нет, то куки не принимаются с сайта.

Есть сайт на Yii 2.0.13. Как сделать так, чтоб в каждый ответ с сервера добавлялась кука SameSite? Нужно это сделать как-то централизованно в одном месте. В каждый action добавлять вручную эту куку ну совсем тупо.
Знаю что в последних версиях Yii2 эта фича уже реализована. Но обновлять сайт до последней версии не хочу - т.к. он просто на просто может перестать нормально работать (уже пробовал, сыпались ошибки).

Answer (score 0):

В конфиге в секции компонентов можно добавить в каждый ответ

```
'components' => [
    'response' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\Response',
        'on beforeSend' => function ($event) {
            // set cookie
        },
    ],
...
```

Comment: оказывается sameSite - это не отдельная кука, а поле внутри куки. Т.е. в каждую куку, которая передается в браузер надо добавлять поле sameSite. Как это сделать ума не приложу

Comment: В том месте кода из примера, надо получить все куки в массив, пройтись форичем и добавить нужное поле.